# Xcode 7 and cocoaPods problems

Tags: ios, xcode, amazon-s3, cocoapods, xcode7

Im currently working on Xcode 7 i have a project that includes cocoapods.

When i pulled my Git latest version (a working version) it said

" file not found"

to fix this i ran in the Terminal "pod install" I'm also using AWSIOSSdk

version 2.0.15 (an older version) in my app now when i try to run it it says

"[!] Unable to satisfy the following requirements:

`XMLDictionary (~> 1.4.0)` required by `AWSiOSSDKv2 (2.0.15)`
"

i cannot update my AWS sdk it causes me more problems plus I'm unable to locate my podFile.lock it was removed from the folder.

How can i solve these issues I'm currently running on the latest CocoaPods version tried to uninstall and reinstall cocoapods still same issue.

Thanks to anyone who helps.

Comment: You didn't search did you?  I found [this](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/4175) pretty quickly.

Comment: Well i tried it and now it says :

[!] Unable to satisfy the following requirements:

- `XMLDictionary (~> 2.0)` required by `Podfile`

Plus it delete files from my project (The letter D Appears next to classes).

Any ideas?

Comment: But what did you try when you say *I tried it*? Did you try to set it to <1.5?

Comment: Yes i tried to set it to 1.5 and it gives the error i mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

AWS has changed their FW it appears that they are not using the XMLDictionary FW and other FW as well anymore if you will try to update the AWS FW please note that you will have to change your methods names and import statements (BFTask is now AWSTask for example).